# Pasar campos entre clases de distinto nombre c#

Tags: c#

Tengo dos clases TUsuario y otra AppUsuario, lo que pasa es que el servicio que tengo en donde esta AppUsuario se conecta a otro y me regresa un TUsuario, AppUsuario y TUsuario usan los mismos campos pero si intento convertir TUsuario a AppUsuario me da error (Servicio.Tusuario no se puede utilizar como ServicioApp.AppUsuario) y no me deja, hay algun metodo o alguna funcion que detecte los mismos campos y los agregue a AppUsuario?

Trate de usar herencia pero me hace un conflicto entre los dos servicios.

```
 tusuario = (TUsuario)RPComercial.Data.DataModule.DataService.GetUsuario(Datos);
                AppUsuario usuario = new AppUsuario();          
                if (tusuario != null)
                {
                    usuario.Nombre = tusuario.Nombre;
                    usuario.Status = tusuario.Status;
                    usuario.TipoUsuario = tusuario.TipoUsuario;
                    usuario.TipoUsuarioID = tusuario.TipoUsuarioID;
                    usuario.Codigo = tusuario.Codigo;
                }
```

Comment: Ponga el código

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar mejor tu pregunta? Emplea fragmentos de código para que veamos que estas usando 
y como poder ayudarte.

Comment: ya edite, quiero evitarme hacer para todas las clases volver a asignar los campos a la otra clase ya que los otros metodos que tengo son de campos mas extensos y siento que se podria reutilizar mas eficiente con una funcion o algo.

Comment: como estas declarando las propiedades de ambas clases?

Comment: @Manny los campos son del mismo tipo, solo las clases me las toma como si fueran distintas por estar en distintos servicios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para convertir de una clase a otra puede usar `AutoMapper`

[AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html)

la libreria la agregas usando nuget

entonces defines la configuracion

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<TUsuario, AppUsuario>());

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
AppUsuario appUsuario = mapper.Map<AppUsuario>(tusuario);
```

En realidad lo idea es que la configuracion se realice en el `startup` de la aplicaicon y tengas disponible la instancia del mapper en toda la aplicaicon inyectando la instancia, pero bueno, sino tendras que configurar he instanciar cada vez que la uses

Comment: Me serviria para listas tambien?

Comment: claro, sigues mapeando la entidad, pero despues usas `List<AppUsuario> appUsuario = mapper.Map<List<AppUsuario>>(list_tusuario);` pasando por supuesto la lista de tusuario

Comment: Quiero hacer un metodo para que me tome todo tipo de clases sin necesidad de declararlas, intente:

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<obj1.GetType(), obj2.GetType()>());

pero extrañamente me dice que no hay ningun metodo que acepte 2 argumentos.

Comment: Eso no se puede hacer, es una libreria de mapping, pero no hace magia. Debes definir los tipos que quieres convertir, puede definir mas de un mapping si lo necesitas, pero debes declarar de que clase a cual otra se quiere convertir

Comment: Para listas me esta dando un error, no se si por que dentro tambien tengo otra lista de otra clase pero como estan en distintos servers...

Comment: no entendi que tiene que ver el server, pero si hay entidades dentro de otras entidades solo debe mapearlas y automapper se encarga de convertirlas

Comment: servers (servicios), tengo una clase y si dentro de la misma hay una propiedad de otra clase que esta dentro de ese mismo servicio al pasarlo por automapper y querer convertirlo a la clase del otro servicio con su propiedad tambien diferente de ese mismo servicio me truena, tuve que adaptar mejor mi metodo y tuve que dejar del lado el automapper.

Answer (score 1):

Tenes varias opciones para resolver tu problema, una, podría ser definir un [operador de conversión](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-ES/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators).

Por ejemplo..

```
class AppUsuario
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //La clase TUsuario tiene las mismas propiedades que AppUsuario
    //Entonces defino un operador de conversión explícito
    public static explicit operator AppUsuario(TUsuario tUsuario)
    {
        if (tUsuario != null)
            return new AppUsuario
        {
            Id = tUsuario.Id,
            Nombre = tUsuario.Nombre
        };
        return default;
    }
}
```

Ahora, el siguiente código, sería válido.

```
TUsuario user = new TUsuario
{
    Id = 0,
    Nombre = "Carlos"
};

AppUsuario appUser = (AppUsuario)user;
```

Ejemplo funcionando en [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wPHfML)

---

Otra posibilidad, es usar una librería de terceros, tal como **[AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/)**

Con la que bastaría definir un perfil con un mapeo sencillo como

```
CreateMap<TUsuario,AppUsuario>();
```

De esta manera, ya podríamos mapear objetos de tipo `TUsuario` a `AppUsuario` o incluso, podemos hacer el mapeo bidireccional para que también podamos convertir de tipo `AppUsuario` a `TUsuario` usando el metodo [ReverseMap()](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html)

```
CreateMap<TUsuario,AppUsuario>().ReverseMap();
```

Luego, sólo para mapear el objeto, sólo deberías hacer lo siguiente

```
AppUsuario appUser = mapper.Map<AppUsuario>(user);
```

Ejemplo funcionando en [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u09aHV)

Comment: Pero esa seria seria necesario especificarle de que tipo es la clase, queria que me sirviera para todas las clases que voy a necesitar.

Answer (score 0):

Hice un metodo que me funciono, aunque igual creo que voy a probar el AutoMapper que me dijeron en una respuesta, dejo mi metodo por si le sirve a alguien, solo tendria que reconvertir el objecto de respuesta al tipo de clase.

```
  private object ConvertirObjeto(object varLectura, object varEscritura)
    {

        foreach (var  PropertyInfo in varLectura.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            foreach (var _property in varEscritura.GetType().GetProperties()
               .Where(x => x.Name == PropertyInfo.Name))
            {
                _property.SetValue(varEscritura, PropertyInfo.GetValue(varLectura, null));

            }
        }
        return varEscritura;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Intentaste usar Herencia con una Interface?

```
public interface ITipo
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
    }
public class AppUsuario : ITipo

{
    public AppUsuario()
    {
    }

    public string id { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
}
public class Tusuario : ITipo
{
    public tUsuario()
    {
    }

    public string id { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
}
```

//En tu metodo o clase donde ejecutas la logica:

```
ITipo tipoGenerico;

tipoGenerico = (TUsuario)RPComercial.Data.DataModule.DataService.GetUsuario(Datos);
            AppUsuario usuario = new AppUsuario();          
            if (tusuario != null)
            {
                usuario = tipoGenerico;
            }
```

Comment: Tuve problemas al usar herencia por que las clases estan generadas con las herramientas de los servicios.

Comment: recibes la informacion sobre un tipo de servicio Rest?

Comment: Es un servicio hecho en Remobjects y tiene una herramienta para definir las clases que usara el servicio, y este servicio se conecta a otro servicio; el caso es que cuando quiero heredar una clase del servicio viejo al servicio nuevo, al ejecutar el servicio me lo detecta como si fuera el viejo.

Comment: pero recibes un json?

Comment: Recibo un objeto tambien del otro lado, remobjects te exporta unas clases para que la uses con el cliente. Por ejemplo en Xcode recibo:
var usuario = servicio.GetUsuario("user","pass"); y esa variable usuario trae los mismos campos que necesitaba convertir.